# Instantiate object defined in other XAML file

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a XAML file that looks something like this:

```
<!-- File1.xaml -->
<m:SomeName xmlns:m="clr-namespace:SomeNamespace">
    ...
</m:SomeName>
```

I have another XAML file in which I would like to instantiate the object defined in `File1.xaml` and set it to a property on another object defined in `File2.xaml`:

```
<m:SomeOtherName xmlns:m="clr-namespace:SomeNamespace">
   <m:SomeOtherName.Property>
       <!-- I want File1.xaml object here -->
   </m:SomeOtherName.Property>
</m:SomeOtherName>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `XAML` for this object, then this object needs to extend `DependencyObject`. The easiest way is to create a `UserControl`:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="SomeNamespace.SomeName"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

    <!-- Other XAML content -->

</UserControl>
```

which has its own code behind file:

```
namespace SomeNamespace
{
    public sealed partial class SomeName : UserControl
    {
        public SomeName()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can instantiate the control in other parts of your app:

```
<m:SomeOtherName xmlns:m="clr-namespace:SomeNamespace">
   <m:SomeOtherName.Property>
       <someNamespace:SomeName />
   </m:SomeOtherName.Property>
</m:SomeOtherName>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create this shared object in `App.Xaml` file as a `Resource`. Then this same object will be present in both the files.